# How do I work with ids as a primary key in IBM'S DB2

Tags: python, sql, db2

I have a flask server that needs to register an account. This account will have an ID as the primary key. I set the primary key to be

```
usr_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1)
```

when I try to save the info to the db (using python), I try

```
save_data = 'INSERT INTO myTable(name, email, psw) VALUES(?, ?, ?)'
        param = name, email, psw #these are python vars
        stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, save_data)#conn is the connection to db2 in python
        ibm_db.execute(stmt, param)
```

My problem is, 'myTable' has that userid that auto increments. When I tried registering for the first time I got an error saying I was giving too few values. I figured that the missing one would be userid, so I specified which values I was giving as shown in the code above. Now I get a new error. I don't understand what I should do to make the db2 generate the number and I am not sure if that error still relates to the missing value I talked about

the error message I get in the terminal is

```
Exception: Statement Execute Failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0302N  The value of a host variable in the EXECUTE or OPEN statemen SQLCODE=-302ange for its corresponding use.  SQLSTATE=22001
```

Comment: Please include the whole table structure in the question. You may be missing the value for a column that has a `NOT NULL` constraint.

Comment: the table is just these three vars and the userid. I double-checked and my code is using non null values for these and sending nothing for the id

Comment: I did some more digging and I need to pass one argument to the function as the usr_id. What should I give it?

Comment: Check [SQL0302N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0302n), one of the three values doesn't fit the corresponding column

Answer (score 1):

with a table defined like this:

```
create table so.my_table(id int not null primary key generated always as identity, 
                         name varchar(10), 
                         email varchar(20), 
                         psw varchar(16))";
```

this works just fine:

```
save_data_sql = 'insert into so.my_table(name, email, psw) values(?, ?, ?)'
params = 'kkuduk', 'kkuduk@ibm', 'strongPassword'
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, save_data_sql)
ibm_db.execute(stmt, params)
```

i.e.

```
In [16]: ibm_db.execute(stmt, params)
In [17]: stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn,"select * from  so.my_table")
In [18]: result = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
In [19]: result
Out[19]: {'ID': 1, 'NAME': 'kkuduk', 'EMAIL': 'kkuduk@ibm', 'PSW': 'strongPassword'}
```

other option is to bind parametes on-by-one

```
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, save_data_sql)
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, 'kkuduk')
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 2, 'kkuduk@ibm')
ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 3, 'strongPassword')
ibm_db.execute(stmt)
```

An error SQL0302N could be returned e.g. if I would try a value out for range, so likely the issue is not your `usr_id` column, but one of 3 that you are actually trying to explicitly insert.